# Implement Svelte into a single HTML container

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am interested in the Svelte framework simply because of it's simplicity and ease of use. As an in-house department in a regional team, we don't have full access to any backend file management for any of our sites.

We have a proprietary cell-by-cell website builder and we do everything in code (Putting our HTML code in a single cell) to get around the limitations of the site builder.

Wondering if there's a way to implement the Svelte framework under these limitations.

Have not found any resources on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Svelte is a compiled language, so writing Svelte syntax within your proprietary editor would require someone on the backend implementing the compiler into the cell editor.

Alternatively, Svelte will create a 'build' directory when your project is built.  You could, then copy the necessary code into your cell editor.  This, however, would require that you/your team maintain that code with some sort of agreed on file organization outside of your site builder (github, maybe?), as well as inside of it.

In either case, I heavily recommend going through [the documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs/introduction) before getting too far into the weeds.

Answer (score 0):

This is a build system issue. You need to compile the application and inline everything into one HTML (fragment).

Many people use Vite, which also is the default for SvelteKit, and people have asked for a way to compile to a single file [here on GitHub](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/621). Someone wrote a plugin to help with that but it probably generates full pages. Worst case you would just have to write your own to generate a fragment that can be pasted into the site builder.

The Svelte compiler itself outputs JS & CSS, if you want to work at that low level.

Answer (score 0):

You can build custom elements with svelte, maybe that's the way to go?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements

https://svelte.dev/docs/custom-elements-api